# I want to have 2 programs launch side by side when windows starts

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8.1

I am working on some kind of schedule screen, and I need to have Outlook calendar and an IP camera both side by side on my screen. Later this will be implemented on a television with a compute stick, so I won't be able to launch the programs every time when I start the compute stick. Hence the question, is there a way to start 2 programs side by side automatically when Windows starts?

Answer (score 4):

*There is no shortcut to do this. But windows snap is the thing to do this. There is no dos command to call snap directly. So using VBscript you can call snap from command... You can use something like this:*

**Step 1:** Create a VBscript file like 'Snap.vbs' using any editor.

**Step 2:** Paste this code to 'Snap.vbs' file:

```
dim objShell
set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.TileVertically
set objShell = nothing
```

**Step 3:** Now write a batch file "StartOutlook.bat" to start outlook calendar:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15 
OUTLOOK.exe /select outlook:calendar
```

**Step 4:** Now Create another batch file to run "StartOutlook.bat", IP Camera App and "snap.vbs". After starting each app give some time to start and functioning properly:

```
start OpenOutlook.bat
timeout /t 15
start ipcam.exe
timeout /t 5
start snap.vbs
```

**Step 5:** Start this batch file each when the computer boots.

**To run a batch file at start up:**

> start >> all programs >> right-click startup >> open >> right click
> batch file >> create shortcut >> drag shortcut to startup folder.

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but when i use the command start outlook.exe (or the path) /select outlook:calendar i just get a plain calendar and not the ones from my office, is there a way to use vbs to go to calendar after outlook has started normally in inbox?

Comment: I have modified the batch.If your Outlook is configured and functioning properly it will automatically open your office calendar.If this solution is also not working properly adjust the sleeping time according to your computer performance by changing "timeout /t <Waiting time in second>".

Comment: Use `cd /D` instead of just `cd` to also change the drive if necessary…

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is what you need, my English level is not very good, but you can use Startup folder. Every program you put in will be opened when windows starts. In windows 7 you can find it in the Start Menu, in Windows 8 and Windows 10 you can find it typing shell:startup in the run prompt.
Hope you understand what I try to say.

Comment: Yea, this is what i need, i got this far, but now i need to start them side by side automatically, so i dont need to attach a keyboard and mouse to the stick every morning