# Would like to code a kiosk-mode script for opening two websites one at a time using vbs only

Tags: vbscript, kiosk-mode

*REVISED the script needs to be able to allow for both pages to be readily accessible, maybe via ALT-TAB for the intended use.

I would like to compose a script to use loops to open one website at a time in kiosk mode using vbs, but readily switching between them. I have provided a sample script that is not quite useful for what I need at the moment and this is why some guidance or help would be appreciated. Ultimately, the goal is to have one page open in kiosk mode and then switch to another window readily(back and forth as needed). Only thing is that they should be in kiosk mode. Can anyone tell me if this is plausible to do in vbs? Any and all help appreciated.

kiosk-mode would be ideal for the purpose I need it for as it is for use for surveys for research purposes, we will be setting up a survey for candidates to take. vbs is the only approved method I can use at the moment. We have a feedback response from that we will be using so that we can utilize the feedback by each instance that a candidate encountered to address for quality concerns.

```
const navOpenInNewTab = &h0800

Dim objIE
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate("about:blank")

objIE.Navigate "http://www.google.com",CLng(navOpenInNewTab)

objIE.FullScreen=True
Set objDoc = objIE.Document.Body
strHTML = "<H1>Display this message.</H1>"
objDoc.InnerHTML = strHTML
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.StatusBar = False
objShell.Run ("iexplore -k")
WScript.Sleep(500)

objIE.Quit
```

As it stands right now, with my limited capacity in knowledge in vbs I have limitations, the code presented here opens two windows instead of tabs(most likely an error in my code and understanding)

Answer (score 0):

This opens up google, waits for it to close (is with -k so kiosk mode, you can close it from taskbar), and then microsoft.com appears:

```
Option Explicit 

Dim objShell

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "iexplore -k http://google.ro" , 1, true


objShell.Run "iexplore -k http://microsoft.com" , 1, true

set objShell = nothing

Wscript.Quit
```

This is done using the .run arguments 1 (show execution) and true (wait for process to finish)

https://ss64.com/vb/run.html

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try.

Comment: I apologize as the ask has changed, both websites need to be able to switch as needed

Comment: What do you mean swith as needed?

Comment: The only way to swith is with alt-tab, in that case change the script to not wait for the execution.

Comment: Again, you could change the above script, instead of true on the run commands, place false and this will open up two internet explorers in kiosk mode. Then with Alt-tab you could switch between them. However, if you want something side by side you can check the following topic:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608612/i-want-to-have-2-programs-launch-side-by-side-when-windows-starts
. What you want should be done with AutoIT and sends the Win+Left or Right commands:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/271416-script-that-will-open-two-folders-and-auto-snap

Comment: I attempted to modify the script as instructed replacing 'true' with 'false' this still opens one window at a time, not sure if there is another aspect that doesn't allow for them to both open simultaneously??

Comment: Just tested it, both commands placed as:

objShell.Run "iexplore -k http://google.ro", 1, false


objShell.Run "iexplore -k http://microsoft.com", 1, false

And opens up two kiosk windows at the same time.

Comment: I'll try again:" Dim objShell

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "iexplore -k http://google.com" , 1, false

objShell.Run "iexplore -k http://microsoft.com" , 1, false

set objShell = nothing

Wscript.Quit "

Comment: Dim objShell

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "iexplore -k http://google.com" , 1, false

objShell.Run "iexplore -k http://microsoft.com" , 1, false

set objShell = nothing

Wscript.Quit